# Hardened multiplication and division operation in C++

Tags: c++, templates, math

Everyone should know that the * and / operators are good footguns in C and C++:

- Multiplication with * can easily overflow: 32bit * 32bit = 64bit
- (Integer-) Division can cause undefined behaviour: X / 0 = ???

Is there anything in the C++ standard library that helps to avoid these issues, like a std::divide_int that throws a div_zero exception or a std::multiply_int that throws an int_overflow exception? If not, why?
In my opinion, having such functions easily accessible would help to write safe code.

Comment: just add if statements or try catch statements

Comment: or turn up your compiler flags

Comment: @NendoTaka These kind of errors usually don't manifest in exceptions!

Comment: Most compilers may throw a warning about such issues. Consider them seriously!

Comment: Interesting I guess they don't but the if statements should be able to stop the division issue

Comment: @NendoTaka Typically a division by zero causes a FPU segfault, but not an exception. Maybe, we're mismatching by terminology?

Comment: Of course I could implement the functions myself, but my question was about something similiar in the standard library.

Comment: Why isn't in the standard library? Because nobody has put it in there. (Possibly due to lack of demand or the obvious performance implications.). If you feel strongly enough about it, then make a proposal for it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: There isn't. And that's probably because those integer types aren't supposed for "real" math, they're for indexing, iterating and such where you *really should* know your exact bounds and conditions either way.

Comment: @DanielJour that might be the reason. Sadly that's not the case everytime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard library functionality for this but you might want to take a look at the [SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/) library.

If you're using clang you might also want to experiment with [`-fsanitize=integer`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I'm looking for (not using standard ints), but pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing for this in standard library. The reason for this is that integer overflows are not neccessarily propagated from CPU. Some CPUs has the flags to check for integer overflow, some don't. As simple as that.